# Printando somente o ultimo resultado

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou montando um PDF pelo `MPDF`, utilizando um `HTML`. Porém ele ta `printando` somente o ultimo resultado e deveria `printar` todos, pois esta dentro de um `foreach`. Como fazer para ele printar todos os resultado um em cada linha.

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
        $html = '
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <table class="flat-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Nosso Numero</th>
            <th>Ocorrencia</th>
            <th>Vlr Boleto</th>
            <th>Matricula</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Competencia</th>
            <th>Valor Devido</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>'.$v->nosso_numero.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->ocorrencia.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->vlr_boleto.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->matricula.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->nome.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->competencia.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->valor_devido.'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
    }
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Para cada elemento do foreach vc sobrescreve o valor de `$html` por isso só parece o último.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente **seu loop está errado**, pois está colocando a estrutura toda da página dentro da repetição, então você iria gerar diversas "páginas" em uma única.

Então, como feito pelo Márcio, deve-se fazer somente repetição nos registros:

```
# Gera as tags principais, e o cabeçalho da table
$html = ' <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <table class="flat-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Nosso Numero</th>
            <th>Ocorrencia</th>
            <th>Vlr Boleto</th>
            <th>Matricula</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Competencia</th>
            <th>Valor Devido</th>
          </tr>';

# Gera linhas da tabela
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
        $html .= '
            <tr>
             <td>'.$v->nosso_numero.'</td>
             <td>'.$v->ocorrencia.'</td>
             <td>'.$v->vlr_boleto.'</td>
             <td>'.$v->matricula.'</td>
             <td>'.$v->nome.'</td>
             <td>'.$v->competencia.'</td>
             <td>'.$v->valor_devido.'</td>
            </tr>
    ';
    }

# Fecha a table e as outras tags principais
$html .= '</table>
    </body>
    </html>';
```

#### Complementando

Você deve usar `.=`, para ir adicionando os dados a sua variável `$html`, pois se não tiver o `.` que significa concatenação, você irá substituir todos os valores, ficando somente com o último, que no caso do exemplo acima, seria somente `</table>`.

Answer (score 2):

Boas,
você tem de concatenar a variável $html em cada iteração:

```
$html = ' <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <table class="flat-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Nosso Numero</th>
            <th>Ocorrencia</th>
            <th>Vlr Boleto</th>
            <th>Matricula</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Competencia</th>
            <th>Valor Devido</th>
          </tr>';

foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
        $html .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$v->nosso_numero.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->ocorrencia.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->vlr_boleto.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->matricula.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->nome.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->competencia.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->valor_devido.'</td>
            </tr>
    ';
    }

$html .= '</table>
    </body>
    </html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou um detalhe na `$html`, agora ela concatena `$html` e não subscreve. com o uso do `+=` irá concatenar em vez de subscrever.

```
<?php
$html = "";
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
        $html+= '
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <table class="flat-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Nosso Numero</th>
            <th>Ocorrencia</th>
            <th>Vlr Boleto</th>
            <th>Matricula</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Competencia</th>
            <th>Valor Devido</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>'.$v->nosso_numero.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->ocorrencia.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->vlr_boleto.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->matricula.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->nome.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->competencia.'</td>
            <td>'.$v->valor_devido.'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
    }
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Com isso ocorre: `Message: Undefined variable: html`

Comment: Opa desculpa, fiz a correção já

Comment: @Bulfaitelo dessa forma criará diversas "páginas" em usa mesma página. Está correto isso!?

Comment: @rbz vai depender de como está o autopagebreak do mptf dele. normalmente é eu deixo auto.

Comment: Como cara, ele vai imprimir 1 folha para cara registro !? Então não tem porque a table...

Comment: O sinal de + é de soma, não de concatenação em PHP.

Comment: @rbz na verdade ele não definiu isso, mas o importante é ele conseguir imprimir

Comment: @Sam no caso quando se usa `+=` por padrão o php concatena.

Comment: "mas o importante é ele conseguir imprimir" ou fazer certo !? De forma, você está "corrigindo o erro".